# How to update the style of a JSF component at runtime

Tags: java, jsf

How to update the style of a JSF component at runtime, I must clarify that I want to change the position of the component and in some cases hide it.

```
<ui:define name="reverso" id="reverso" >
       <!-- Logo Estado Próspero -->
       <p:graphicImage value="./resources/oficiales/prospero.png" style="width: 90px; height: 50px;position: relative; left: 150px" />
       <h:form id="dataRfc">
            <h:outputText id="display_rfc" rendered="true" value="#{IDWizard.rfc}" binding="#{IDWizard.outRfc}" style="color: #333333;text-align:center;margin-top: 30px" />
       </h:form>
</ui:define>

public void setNoPersonal(String noPersonal) {
    this.noPersonal = noPersonal;
    this.outNombre.setValue(this.noPersonal);
    this.outNombre.setRendered(true); 
    this.outRfc.setStyle("text-align:left;color:red;margin-top:2px"); 
    //component.getAttributes().put("style", "color:red");
    this.outRfc.setRendered(true);        
}
```

Comment: Would using a boolean property and a `rendered="#{bean.yourBooleanProperty}"` be an option for you? The same could be done with positions.

Comment: I tried that way but did not succeed.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Please be aware that some older JSF implementations had problems with boolean properties and you might thus need to turn it into a `String` property (values `"true"` or `"false"`). - Also note that you need to rerender your component. Or should everything be done on the client only?

Comment: I added the snippet of the view and the bean

Comment: And I need to control it from server side.

Comment: So please have a look at @BalusC's answer, which is what you need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just use EL expressions in the `style` and `styleClass` attributes. You can use the conditional operator `?:` in EL to print different strings based on a boolean condition.

E.g.

```html
<h:someComponent styleClass="#{bean.show ? 'show' : 'hide'}" />
```

with this getter

```
public boolean isShow() {
    return show;
}
```

and this CSS

```css
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that the above still renders the component to the client side, so you would be able to toggle the visibility using plain JavaScript.

Or, if you actually want to show/hide it entirely server side, then you could use the `rendered` attribute for this instead. It also just accepts EL expressions:

```html
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.show}" />
```

You only need to keep in mind that when this evaluates `false`, then this component is not present in the client side at all, so you won't be able to show it again using plain JavaScript or Ajax. When showing it using Ajax, you need to re-render its parent component instead.

---

**Update** based on your new code snippet, this is not the right way. You should not bind the component to the bean for this. You should also define CSS styles in its own `.css` file which is much easier to maintain and keeps your bean and view from specific CSS clutter.

E.g. (I randomly guess that the styles are dependent on some kind of error/success state)

```html
<h:outputText id="display_rfc" value="#{IDWizard.rfc}" rendered="#{IDWizard.show}"
    styleClass="#{IDWizard.success ? 'success' : 'error'}" />
```

with those getters

```
public boolean isShow() {
    return show;
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}
```

and this CSS

```css
.success {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.error {
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

You just have to set those booleans accordingly in bean's (post)constructor or action(listener) method.

Comment: Sorry, I am not immediately able to fly/beam over to you to see with my own eyes what exactly fails. Can you please elaborate "doesn't work" in more detail?

Comment: The EL on StyleClass works but it doesn't apply the style settings to the component, only generates the html value.

Comment: So, you're new to CSS as well? It should generate either `class="success"` or `class="error"`. This should work if you have the `.success {}` and `.error {}` declarations in some `style.css` file which you include as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` in the HTML `<head>`.

Comment: The css file has the appropriate classes and is loaded but does not apply the style to the component.

Comment: You need to check with Firebug's "Inspect Element" what exactly has failed. Open page in Friefox (with Firebug plugin installed) and rightclick the part which is presented by the `<h:outputText>` and then choose *Inspect Element* option. Firebug should now show up with all assigned CSS declarations in the right side. You need to verify if your definied styles are there and are not been overridden by another styles (e.g. the PrimeFaces own styles).

Comment: It generates class = "error" or class = "success" but shows no change.

Comment: Yes I understood that. The JSF part is working perfectly fine, it has generated the right HTML. Only the CSS/webbrowser part is not working fine yet, it has not applied the style. This problem is not caused by JSF/webserver. You need to naildown and fix that in the CSS/webbrowser side. See my previous comment for an explanation how to do that with Firebug. You're a web genius, are you? :)

Comment: I deleted the browser cache and now correctly applies css styles, but if I change the styleClass attribute at run time by:

component.getAttributes (). put ("styleClass", "hide");

because if I change the value of the variable "show" has no effect on the component.

Comment: excuse my inexperience but I aspire to be a web genius :)

Comment: You should not do it in the backing bean. You should do it in the view side using EL, exactly as I demonstrated in my answer. For example, `styleClass="#{bean.show ? (bean.success ? 'success' : 'error') : 'hide'}"`. **Remove** the `binding` and do not ever think to use it unless you really know what you're doing and understand what it should be used for :)